# AngularJS : submit disabled until HTML 5 valid and disable after submit prevent multi submit

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to keep my submit button `disabled` until form is HTML valid which I have managed to do like so:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" ng-disabled="mainPaymentForm" ng-click="disableButton()"><%button%></button>
```

In my controller I have this:

```
// Disable form on submit
$scope.disableButton = function(){
        $scope.button = "Loading...";
        $scope.submit.disable = true; // This doesn't work
};
```

Overall I am just trying to keep button disabled until valid / and prevent multiple submit clicks once valid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

HTML  code

`ng-disabled="mainPaymentForm.$invalid || clickDisable"`

JS controller code

```
// this will unable button if form becomes valid
$scope.$watch('mainPaymentForm.$invalid', function(){
        $scope.clickDisable = false;
});

// this will disable it on click
$scope.disableButton = function(){
        $scope.button = "Loading...";
        $scope.clickDisable = true;
};
```